# Pure css way to prevent scrollbar pushing content to the left?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

Is there a way to prevent scrollbar from pushing content, or the entire page to the left with pure css? 
I mean no hacks or anything.

I tried two javascript solutions:

1) Set body to overflow hidden, store the body.offsetWidth in a variable, then overflow visible and then subtract that offsetWidth with the current body.offsetWidth and apply the difference to the right margin.

2) Calculate the offsetWidth and apply it on the wrapper div on every resize.

What didnt work:

1) Position absolute.

2) Floating everything to the left was a bad idea.

3) Leaving the scrollbar visible (Looks bad).

4) Overflow-y hidden makes things user unfriendly.

Comment: @TimTroiano same thing as with overflow visible. I get a bar on right of every page even if its not needed but maybe im overthinking it.

Comment: Please make a fiddle for this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no other way to prevent your problem.
Just use

```
     body {
        overflow:hidden;
     }
```

As an alternative, I recommend you to use a Framework for custom scroll bars. Or disable the scrollbar as shown in the above snippet and emulate it with an absolute positioned  and some JS.
Of course you will have to consider calculating the height of the page and the offset of the scrollbar thumb.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Can you create an example?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll gladly do that when I have time. :)

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try to implement your suggestion! Very good idea.

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of ways to go around this *issue* though normally you won't mind a little push to the left:

1. Give `overflow-y: scroll` to `body` and make sure always there *is* a scrollbar.
2. Make use of the fact that viewport width includes the scrollbar while percentages do not account for it:

   a. Giving `width: 100vw` to `body` element, or

   b. Giving `margin-left: calc(100vw - 100%)` to the `html` element so that scrollbar or not, you have a fixed area to work on.
3. There is even a *deprecated* [`overflow: overlay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#Values) property that draws over the page instead of shifting it to the left.

Answer (score 4):

try this new CSS property

```
html{
scrollbar-gutter: stable; 
}
```

Comment: side note: [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter)

Comment: Note that this only seems to work for vertical scrolling

Comment: Note that this also has rather poor browser support, as of September 2023. See: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_scrollbar-gutter

Answer (score 3):

Just give your body a width of 100vw like this:

```
body{
   width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: This will cause the horizontal scroll to appear

Answer (score 1):

Even though all the answers above are correct, I stumbled upon this issue and I had to come up with another solution.

Since my content width takes up the whole page and it has some properties to justify in the center, it was being pushed to the left and these options didn't prevent it from happening.

What fixed the problem for me was to add a padding of the size of the scroll when the scroll is added on hover.

I tested on Chrome and Edge. It's not a perfect fix but it is enough for what I need right now.

```
.scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 91vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px !important;
}

.scrollable:hover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 91vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-left: 16.8px !important;
}
```

Comment: Well, this is risky because native scroll bar widths change across different browsers and OS's.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the horizontal scrollbar, you can use overflow-x, so it won't affect your vertical scroll:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set overflow-x to hidden on the element that has the scrollbar (usually this would be the body or the immediate children of it).

I had the same problem on my nextjs app which already had overflow-x set to hidden on the body. The below solution worked for me

```
#__next{
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```